# Using adds in app build using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, iad, adsense

I have created an app using jquery mobile. I will be using phonegap to build the android app . I would like to know how can i add google ads in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plugin for Cordova & iAd. It has problems with landscape orient., but everything else works fine.
https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-iad

Comment: Thanks a lot FlyingLemon